# Difference between MEF and Simple Use

Tags: c#, dll, reference, export, mef

what is the difference between using MEF to reusing components and Simply Adding Reference to the DLL of another project in current project? I mean that we also add reference to the project we import in our current project. Then how it is different from conventional form of component use?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the timing mef can be different on each start up references on each compile process.